# What is the difference between "|" and "or"?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

i am using numpy :

```
In [83]: names = np.array(['Bob', 'Joe', 'Will', 'Bob', 'Will', 'Joe', 'Joe'])

In [93]: mask = (names == 'Bob') | (names == 'Will')
```

why can not I use "or" instead of "|"?

why does it give me error when I remove the pretenses in In[93] ?

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This information is easily findable in the documentation.

Comment: `|` is bitwise OR, `or` is logical OR

Comment: what is the error for in the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`and` is python's **logical-AND** operator.

`|` is python's **bitwise-OR** operator (not **bitwise-AND**, as your question might suggest), which numpy overrides in order to make it the numpy **element-wise-OR**.

Numpy couldn't have overridden `and` nor `or` to work element-wise, because `and` and `or` are not overridable in python. Therefor, the bitwise operators are overridden in numpy.